Why reshape is needed for Sequential models after minmaxscaler class? and how to use?
My recent project is based on 'Stock Prediciton" I'm working on df["Open"] as nd.array.
Trying to understand intuitively how this works and whether my predicted data will be correct or not.
A brief explanation about the coding part, not the theoretical.

I suggest you to be adventurous and just print the output of minmaxscaler. This will help you understand everything intuitively

Hey thanks, I've been doing it lately and i haven't seen much improvement... i have started out digging .py's of packages/libraries and read blogs mostly. But it seems there's a lack of bridge where code and theory connects. But hey, I'm doing well thanks
